# Create a custom scala collection where map defaults to returning the custom collection?

Tags: scala, collections, type-inference, scala-collections, scala-2.10

The trait `TraversableLike[+A, +Repr]` allows one to make a collection where *some* functions will return a `Repr`, while others continue to return the type parameter `That` on the function. Is there a way to define a `CustomCollection[A]` where functions like `map`, `++`, and others will default `That` as `Repr` if not inferred otherwise?

Here is a code snippet that hopefully describes what I would like:

```
case class CustomCollection[A](list: List[A]) extends TraversableLike[A, CustomCollection[A]] {
  protected[this] def newBuilder = new CustomCollectionBuilder[A]
  def foreach[U](f: (A) => U) {list foreach f}
  def seq = list
}

class CustomCollectionBuilder[A] extends mutable.Builder[A, CustomCollection[A]] {
  private val list = new mutable.ListBuffer[A]()
  def += (elem: A): this.type = {
    list += elem
    this
  }
  def clear() {list.clear()}
  def result(): CustomCollection[A] = CustomCollection(list.result())
}

object CustomCollection extends App {
  val customCollection = CustomCollection(List(1, 2, 3))
  println(customCollection filter {x => x == 1}) // CustomCollection(1)
  println(customCollection map {x => x + 1}) // non-empty iterator
}
```

I would like the last line to be `CustomCollection(2, 3, 4)`.

Comment: I logged in just to +1 om-nom-nom for being just three mins behind the post.  There doesn't seem to be a "Timely edit!" button with a thumbs up logo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set up a companion object which provides the refined `CanBuildFrom` instance:

```
import collection.TraversableLike
import collection.generic.{CanBuildFrom, GenericCompanion, GenericTraversableTemplate,
  TraversableFactory}
import collection.mutable.{Builder, ListBuffer}

object CustomCollection extends TraversableFactory[CustomCollection] {
  def newBuilder[A] = new CustomCollectionBuilder[A]
  implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, CustomCollection[A]] = 
    new CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, CustomCollection[A]] {
       def apply(): Builder[A, CustomCollection[A]] = new CustomCollectionBuilder()
       def apply(from: Coll): Builder[A, CustomCollection[A]] = apply()
    }
}
case class CustomCollection[A](list: List[A]) extends Traversable[A]
with TraversableLike[A, CustomCollection[A]]
with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, CustomCollection] {
  override def companion: GenericCompanion[CustomCollection] = CustomCollection
  def foreach[U](f: A => U) { list foreach f }
  override def seq = list
}

class CustomCollectionBuilder[A] extends Builder[A, CustomCollection[A]] {
  private val list = new ListBuffer[A]()
  def += (elem: A): this.type = {
    list += elem
    this
  }
  def clear() {list.clear()}
  def result(): CustomCollection[A] = CustomCollection(list.result())
}

val customCollection = CustomCollection(List(1, 2, 3))
val f = customCollection filter {x => x == 1} // CustomCollection[Int]
val m = customCollection map {x => x + 1}     // CustomCollection[Int]
```

Comment: Great answer! I had a feeling I needed to use a cbf, but I couldn't find the most generic way to do it. Is there anywhere I can read more about the specifics of the collections api like this? I.e. how should I know that in addition to extending `TraversableLike` I also need to extend `GenericTraversableTemplate`?

Comment: @dicarlo2 - I generally look at the source code of the class most similar to what I'm doing and copy what they mixed in.  I've found this more reliable than any other approach in the absence of knowing exactly what functionality is provided by each trait (and how you want all the diamond-shape inheritance patterns to resolve).

Comment: @RexKerr Heh, that's the same thing I usually do, after posting the question I got as far as `TraversableFactory` before I had to step away from the computer, still who knows how many files I would have looked through to find all the diamond-shape inheritance patterns. Too bad there isn't a better reference and the documentation doesn't always illuminate what the relations are between each trait.

Comment: @dicarlo2 - I think the collections library is one of those "How many triangles are there in this picture" puzzles in disguise.

Comment: Best is probably to stick the existing collections, and if you need extra functionality, try to add them type-class style with Scala 2.10's `IsTraversableLike` helper.