# Scala unique sequence

Tags: scala, set, sequence

In Scala (2.10), I'd like an immutable SeqLike collection (supporting indexing) which offers a SetLike interface to the user, and won't allow duplicate elements. Ideally, this would implement both SetLike and SeqLike, but this isn't possible, so I have to pick one. My first idea was as follows:

```
sealed class IndexableSet[A] ( private val values : Seq[A] )
    extends Set[A]
    with SetLike[A,IndexableSet[A]]
{
    override def empty : IndexableSet[A] = new IndexableSet[A]( Seq[A]() )

    def + ( elem : A ) : IndexableSet[A] = values.contains( elem ) match
    {
        case true => this
        case false => new IndexableSet[A]( values :+ elem )
    }

    def - ( elem : A ) : IndexableSet[A] = values.contains( elem ) 
    {
        case true => new IndexableSet[A]( values.filter( _ != elem ) )
        case false => this
    }

    def iterator = values.iterator

    def contains( elem : A ) = values.contains( elem )

    def apply( index : Int ) = values( index )

    def length : Int = values.size

    def contents : Seq[A] = values
}
```

This exposes a suitable interface, but not sortability (no sortBy or sorted)

I'm wondering, therefore, whether to change my implementation to something which implements Seq and SeqLike instead, and fakes the Set interface:

```
sealed class UniqueSeq[A] private ( private val values : IndexedSeq[A] )
    extends SeqLike[A,UniqueSeq[A]]
    with Seq[A]
    with GenericTraversableTemplate[A,UniqueSeq]
{
    def apply( idx : Int ) : A = values( idx )

    def iterator = values.iterator

    def length = values.length

    override def companion: GenericCompanion[UniqueSeq] = new GenericCompanion[UniqueSeq]() 
    {
        def newBuilder[A]: Builder[A, UniqueSeq[A]] = new Builder[A, UniqueSeq[A]] 
        {
            val elems = new ArrayBuffer[A]()
            def +=(a:A) = { elems += a; this } 
            def clear() { elems.clear }
            def result(): UniqueSeq[A] = new UniqueSeq[A](elems)
        }
    }

    def + ( elem : A ) : UniqueSeq[A] = values.contains( elem ) match
    {
        case true => this
        case false => new UniqueSeq[A]( values :+ elem )
    }

    def - ( elem : A ) : UniqueSeq[A] = values.contains( elem ) match
    {
        case true => new UniqueSeq[A]( values.filter( _ != elem ) )
        case false => this
    }
}
```

I'm not sure which is better - or whether there's another way. I know there are things like `TreeSet` but the SortedSet trait doesn't offer the critical indexability.

So the questions are:

1. Is there a clear winner between these two implementations?
2. Is there another way, which is better, in the standard collections?

Comment: This is a topic which comes up occasionally for me too, and I really wish there were a robust solution...  Everything I've tried or seen so far has had shortcomings, such as not working properly with `map` or having the weak `contains(elem: Any)` interface instead of `contains(elem: A)`...

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `SeqLike` backed by a `Seq`. Override any functions which add elements to add the element to the underlying `Seq` followed by a call to `distinct` to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the second solution, possibly modified to maintain both a `Set` and a `Seq` internally:

```
sealed class UniqueSeq[A] private ( values : IndexedSeq[A], valueSet : Set[A] )
    extends SeqLike[A,UniqueSeq[A]]
    with Seq[A]
    with GenericTraversableTemplate[A,UniqueSeq]
{
    def apply( idx : Int ) : A = values( idx )

    def iterator = values.iterator

    def length = values.length

    override def companion: GenericCompanion[UniqueSeq] = new GenericCompanion[UniqueSeq]() 
    {
        def newBuilder[A]: Builder[A, UniqueSeq[A]] = new Builder[A, UniqueSeq[A]] 
        {
            val elems = new ArrayBuffer[A]()
            def +=(a:A) = { elems += a; this } 
            def clear() { elems.clear }
            def result(): UniqueSeq[A] = new UniqueSeq[A](elems)
        }
    }

    def + ( elem : A ) : UniqueSeq[A] = valueSet.contains( elem ) match
    {
        case true => this
        case false => new UniqueSeq[A]( values :+ elem, valueSet + elem )
    }

    def - ( elem : A ) : UniqueSeq[A] = valueSet.contains( elem ) match
    {
        case true => new UniqueSeq[A]( values.filter( _ != elem ), valueSet - elem )
        case false => this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in my application.  It mixes your code with code from this question:
[Create a custom scala collection where map defaults to returning the custom collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299454/create-a-custom-scala-collection-where-map-defaults-to-returning-the-custom-coll)

```
class Unique[A] private (list: Vector[A], set: Set[A]) extends Traversable[A]
    with TraversableLike[A, Unique[A]]
    with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, Unique]
{
    def apply(index: Int): A = list(index)
    override def companion: GenericCompanion[Unique] = Unique
    def foreach[U](f: A => U) { list foreach f }
    override def seq = list

    def +(elem: A): Unique[A] = {
        if (set.contains(elem)) this
        else new Unique(list :+ elem, set + elem)
    }

    def -(elem: A): Unique[A] = {
        if (set.contains(elem)) new Unique(list.filter(_ != elem), set - elem)
        else this
    }

    def --(elems: Traversable[A]): Unique[A] = {
        val set = elems.toSet
        val values2 = list.filterNot(set.contains)
        new Unique(values2, values2.toSet)
    }

    def ++(elems: Traversable[A]): Unique[A] = {
        val list2 = elems.filterNot(set.contains)
        val values2 = list ++ list2
        new Unique(values2, values2.toSet)
    }

    def contains(elem: A): Boolean = set.contains(elem)

    def zipWithIndex: Traversable[(A, Int)] = list.zipWithIndex
}

object Unique extends TraversableFactory[Unique] {
    def newBuilder[A] = new UniqueBuilder[A]

    implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, Unique[A]] = {
        new CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, Unique[A]] {
           def apply(): Builder[A, Unique[A]] = new UniqueBuilder()
           def apply(from: Coll): Builder[A, Unique[A]] = apply()
        }
    }

    class UniqueBuilder[A] extends Builder[A, Unique[A]] {
        private val list = Vector.newBuilder[A]
        private val set = new HashSet[A]()

        def += (elem: A): this.type = {
            if (!set.contains(elem)) {
                list += elem
                set += elem
            }
            this
        }

        def clear() {
            list.clear()
            set.clear()
        }

        def result(): Unique[A] = new Unique(list.result, set.toSet)
    }
}
```